# Can Pro*Fortran connect to Oracle 10g on windows?

Tags: sql, oracle, fortran77

has anyone successfully compiled a pro*fortran program on windows that connects to Oracle 10g?

I can only seem to find information that suggests that pre-compilation of embedded sql is possible against Oracle 8i and earlier.

If you have done this please can you post any links you have for compilers, oracle downloads/articles etc as they would be most appreciated.

(btw sorry if any of the terminology I've used is slightly off as I'd never even seen fortran before today)

Kind regards,

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"pre-compilation of embedded sql is possible against Oracle 8i and earlier."
Haven't heard that. But, at least from the point of view of Pro*C, the pre-compiler hasn't been enhanced since around Oracle 8, so a lot of syntax added for 8i and later won't compile (eg scalar subqueries). Think that applies to data types as well.

It is possible to use newer SQL through dynamic SQL.

Also, 10g (or maybe 10gR2) servers refuse connections from the older client libraries. I think that related to pre-8.1.7 clients.

There is a Pro*Fortran guide in the 10gR2 documentation set, so something must work

```
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14352/toc.htm
```